# Yii crud update - error 400 - Composite Key causing issues

Tags: php, yii

I am having a problem with the UPDATE of the 'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView' in YII php framework.

The link generated by the UPDATE/pencil icon of my 'bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView' produce an 
Error 400.
**The link looks like this**

```
http://mysite/index.php?r=marketingchannel/update&id%5Bid%5D=119&id%5BControllingChannel_id%5D=7
```

**I have tried entering the link manually like this**

```
http://mysite/index.php?r=marketingchannel/update&id=119&ControllingChannel_id=7
```

**then I get the following CDbException**

```
The value for the column "id" is not supplied when querying the table "marketingchannel".
```

**The Stacktrace (of my entering link manually) looks like this:**

**0.** /framework/db/schema/CDbCommandBuilder.php(519): CDbCommandBuilder->createInCondition(CMysqlTableSchema, array("id", "ControllingChannel_id"), array("119"), "`t`.")
**1.**  /framework/db/ar/CActiveRecord.php(1431): CDbCommandBuilder->createPkCriteria(CMysqlTableSchema, "119", "", array(), ...)
**2.**  /protected/controllers/MarketingchannelController.php(158): CActiveRecord->findByPk("119")
**3.**  /protected/controllers/MarketingchannelController.php(89): MarketingchannelController->loadModel("119")
**4.**  unknown(0): MarketingchannelController->actionUpdate("119")
**5.**  /framework/web/actions/CAction.php(108): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(MarketingchannelController, array("119"))
**6.**  /framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(47): CAction->runWithParamsInternal(MarketingchannelController, ReflectionMethod, array("r" => "marketingchannel/update", "id" => "119", "ControllingChannel_id" => "7"))
**7.**  /framework/web/CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams(array("r" => "marketingchannel/update", "id" => "119", "ControllingChannel_id" => "7"))

**This tells me it is finding the id in the url...however cannot process it.**

**Note:** I realise the Gridview is producing a link with [ ] parenthese url encoded. However I dont understand why even when I manually enter a link, it still doesnt work.

**Note2:** I have many Gridviews like this in my application, it is only two that are not working.
Coincidently their models are related by Foreign Keys.
However other Gridviews related to these two, do function properly.

**Update:**
Code of my Controller's Update Action

```
/**
* Updates a particular model.
* If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
* @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
*/
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$model=$this->loadModel($id);

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['Marketingchannel']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Marketingchannel'];
if($model->save())
$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}

$this->render('update',array(
'model'=>$model,
));
}
```

**Update:**
Code of my Model

```
/**
 * This is the model class for table "marketingchannel".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'marketingchannel':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $MarketingChannel
 * @property integer $ControllingChannel_id
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Audibeneid[] $audibenes
 * @property Audibeneid[] $audibenes1
 * @property Controllingchannel $controllingChannel
 * @property Verwendung[] $verwendungs
 */
class Marketingchannel extends CActiveRecord
{
     public $ControllingChannel_search;

    /**
     * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
     * @param string $className active record class name.
     * @return Marketingchannel the static model class
     */
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
    {
        return parent::model($className);
    }

    /**
     * @return string the associated database table name
     */
    public function tableName()
    {
        return 'marketingchannel';
    }

    /**
     * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('ControllingChannel_id', 'required'),
            array('ControllingChannel_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
            array('MarketingChannel', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            //Original   --  array('id, MarketingChannel, ControllingChannel_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
            array('id, MarketingChannel, ControllingChannel_id, ControllingChannel_search', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array relational rules.
     */
    public function relations()
    {
        // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
        // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
        return array(
            'audibenes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Audibeneid', 'MarketingChannel_id'),
            'audibenes1' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Audibeneid', 'MarketingChannel_ControllingChannel_id'),
            'controllingChannel' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Controllingchannel', 'ControllingChannel_id'),
            'verwendungs' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Verwendung', 'MarketingChannel_id'),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return array(
            'id' => 'ID',
            'MarketingChannel' => 'Marketing Channel',
            'ControllingChannel_id' => 'Controlling Channel id',
            'ControllingChannel_search' => 'Controlling Channel',
        );
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
     * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models based on the search/filter conditions.
     */
    public function search()
    {
        // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
        // should not be searched.

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array( 'controllingChannel' );
        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        $criteria->compare('MarketingChannel',$this->MarketingChannel,true);
        $criteria->compare('ControllingChannel_id',$this->ControllingChannel_id);
        $criteria->compare( 'controllingChannel.Controllingchannel', $this->ControllingChannel_search, true );
        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

**Update:**
Sql of my Table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `marketingchannel` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `MarketingChannel` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ControllingChannel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`ControllingChannel_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MarketingChannel_UNIQUE` (`MarketingChannel`),
  KEY `fk_MarketingChannel_ControllingChannel1_idx` (`ControllingChannel_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=137 ;
```

**grid view code.**

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',
array( 'id'=>'marketingchannel-grid', 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(), 'filter'=>$model, 'columns'=>
array( 'id', 'MarketingChannel', array( 'name'=>'ControllingChannel_search', 'value'=>'$data->controllingChannel->ControllingChannel' ), 'ControllingChannel_id', 
array( 'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn', ), ), )); ?>
```

Comment: could you please update the question with your code in marketingchanelle/update action?

Comment: Hi thx for the quick reply. I have updated the Question with my Controller's Update Action.

Comment: let me know if this resolved your problem. accept the answer if its done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please change your action code to this and run again.

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$model=$this->loadModel($id);

// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

if(isset($_POST['Marketingchannel']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Marketingchannel'];
$model->id = $_GET['id'];
if($model->save())
$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}

$this->render('update',array(
'model'=>$model,
));
}
```

The reason could be due to the miss of id. $model->id might not be set.

When you have a composite primary key, you should specify it in the array like done below.

**Updated Answer**

```
public function actionUpdate()
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
$ControllingChannel_id = $_GET['ControllingChannel_id'];
$model = Marketingchannel::model()->findByPk(array(
'id' => $id,
'ControllingChannel_id' => $ControllingChannel_id
));

if(isset($_POST['Marketingchannel']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Marketingchannel'];
if($model->save())
$this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
}

$this->render('update',array(
'model'=>$model,
));
}
```

To resolve the incorrect URL in gridview, you should modify your coding as following and include your url (where to go when pencil icon is clicked) . i.e updateButtonUrl = "the Url to update action"

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array('id'=>'marketingchannel-grid', 'dataProvider'=>$model->search(), 'filter'=>$model,
   'columns'=>
   array('id', 'MarketingChannel', array('name'=>'ControllingChannel_search', 'value'=>'$data->controllingChannel->ControllingChannel')
      , 'ControllingChannel_id',
      array(
         'htmlOptions'=>array('nowrap'=>'nowrap'),
         'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
 'updateButtonUrl'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Marketingchannel/Update/",array("id"=>$data->id, "ControllingChannel_id"=>$data->ControllingChannel_id))',
      ),
      array('class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn'))));
```

Ref : http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/grids/view/gridview.html

Comment: Please print_r your Global param and update the question with your results.

Comment: print_r($_GLOBAL) inside the beginning of your action.

Comment: I will try regenerate the model, form, controller

Comment: can you call the update action by manually setting the URL ? i.e www.yoursite.com/index.php?marketingchannel/update

Comment: ok. can you please update this section $model->id = $_GET['id']; to $model->id = 119; and let me knw the outcome

Comment: public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$id = 111;
$model=$this->loadModel($id);

This produces CDbException

The value for the column "id" is not supplied when querying the table "marketingchannel".

Comment: public function actionUpdate($id)
{
$model=$this->loadModel($id);
if(isset($_POST['Marketingchannel']))
{
$model->attributes=$_POST['Marketingchannel'];
$model->id = 111;                                                                                                          This produces CDbException The value for the column "id" is not supplied when querying the table "marketingchannel"

Comment: @Nischal_b did your last way worked ? have you defined a composite primary key for the table or What is the primary key for this table? tell me against what table your querying ? the model name. i.e User

Comment: can you please also export the sql script related to marketingchannel table?

Comment: added the SQL of the database table

Comment: @Nischal_b yes, issue is figured out. since you have a composite primary key, you should follow it as the updated answer. check now.

Comment: OMG mazraara that was amazing.

Comment: No worries, please make sure to accept the answer if it helped you. you can also up vote if any comment was helpful related to the question.

Comment: Could you also tell me why the Gridview is producing links like this  /index.php?r=marketingchannel/update&id[id]=119&id[ControllingChannel_id]=7   and what I would have to do to get my urlmanager to recognise this

Comment: @Nischal_b sure, please update the question with your cgridview code. it should be under _grid.php

Comment: the marketingchannel views directory only contains the following files      /_form.php
/_search.php
/_view.php
/admin.php
/create.php
/index.php
/update.php
/view.php

Comment: i think better if you can create a new question tagged with yii for cgridview issue.

Comment: it should be admin.php then. check for the view file which has a similar code block  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(

Comment: here is the code                                                  <?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'marketingchannel-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
  'id',
  'MarketingChannel',
  array( 'name'=>'ControllingChannel_search', 'value'=>'$data->controllingChannel->ControllingChannel' ),
  'ControllingChannel_id',
array(
'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
),
),
)); ?>

Comment: Thanks again. I have other gridviews not working so I'm going to try the 'updateButtonUrl'=>null,  solution there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an additional Answer to the Gridview producing the wrong links for a Composite Key Model

```
<?php 

 $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView',array(
'id'=>'marketingchannel-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'MarketingChannel',
        array( 'name'=>'ControllingChannel_search','value'=>'$data->controllingChannel->ControllingChannel' ),
        'ControllingChannel_id',
        array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{view}{update}{delete}',
            'buttons'=>array
            (
                'view' => array
                (
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Marketingchannel/View/",array("id"=>$data->id, "ControllingChannel_id"=>$data->ControllingChannel_id))',
                ),
                'update' => array
                (
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Marketingchannel/Update/",array("id"=>$data->id, "ControllingChannel_id"=>$data->ControllingChannel_id))',
                ),
                'delete'=> array
                (
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("Marketingchannel/Delete/",array("id"=>$data->id, "ControllingChannel_id"=>$data->ControllingChannel_id))',
                ),
            ),
),
),
)); 



?>
```